# Highlighting the content in pre tag... the AngularJS way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a simple AngularJS app to pull text log data record from a database and render it in a pre tag to preserve the formatting.  Trying to add some highlighting with extra markup on the log content failed to render correctly. Instead I get the markup added as a plain text within the content. What I am doing wrong? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/afSsf/

HTML:

```
     <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
          <pre>{{logdata}}</pre>
     </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
     var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

     myApp.factory('Data', function() {
           var Data = {};
           Data.log = "ERROR - error message";
           Data.log = Data.log.replace(/ERROR/mg, '<span style="color:#f00">ERROR</span>')
           return Data;
     });

     function MyCtrl($scope, Data) {
          $scope.logdata = Data.log;
     }
```

Result:

```
     <span style="color:#f00">ERROR</span> - error message
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ng-bind-html-unsafe` directive to bind html data. See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cmyworld/8W2xm/

In latest angular release there is [ng-bind-html](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angBindHtml)

Comment: +1 for ng-bind-html-unsafe. Here is a fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/afSsf/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/afSsf/1/)